Dimension error on responsive grid in nextjs
I'm creating a nextjs portfolio and I'm encountering this issue when I try to make my grid responsive.
Some rows span are bigger than other and some even if i have set a row span span of like 3 they stretch into one.
This only happens to the md property since the lg works well (every row span and col span have an aspect square which is what I'm trying to achieve.



This is my grid:
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { ArrowRightIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

const BentoGrid = ({
  children,
  className,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={cn(
        "grid gap-4",
        "lg:grid-cols-12 lg:grid-rows-6 lg:aspect-[2/1]",
        "md:grid-cols-4 md:grid-rows-16",
        "grid-cols-3 grid-rows-19",
        className,
      )}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const BentoCard = ({
  id,
  title,
  className,
  background,
  Icon,
  description,
  href,
  cta,
}: {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  className: string;
  background: ReactNode;
  Icon: any;
  description: string;
  href: string;
  cta: string;
}) => (
  <div
    key={id}
    className={cn(
      "group relative col-span-3 flex flex-col justify-between overflow-hidden rounded-xl",
      // light styles
      "bg-white [box-shadow:0_0_0_1px_rgba(0,0,0,.03),0_2px_4px_rgba(0,0,0,.05),0_12px_24px_rgba(0,0,0,.05)]",
      // dark styles
      "transform-gpu dark:bg-black dark:[border:1px_solid_rgba(255,255,255,.1)] dark:[box-shadow:0_-20px_80px_-20px_#ffffff1f_inset]",
      className,
    )}
  >
    <div>{background}</div>
    <div className="pointer-events-none z-10 flex transform-gpu flex-col gap-1 p-6 transition-all duration-300 group-hover:-translate-y-10">
      <Icon className="h-12 w-12 origin-left transform-gpu text-neutral-700 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:scale-75" />
      <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-300">
        {title}
      </h3>
      <p className="max-w-lg text-neutral-400">{description}</p>
    </div>

    <div
      className={cn(
        "pointer-events-none absolute bottom-0 flex w-full translate-y-10 transform-gpu flex-row items-center p-4 opacity-0 transition-all duration-300 group-hover:translate-y-0 group-hover:opacity-100",
      )}
    >
      <Button variant="ghost" asChild size="sm" className="pointer-events-auto">
        <a href={href}>
          {cta}
          <ArrowRightIcon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
        </a>
      </Button>
    </div>
    <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-0 transform-gpu transition-all duration-300 group-hover:bg-black/[.03] group-hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/10" />
  </div>
);

export { BentoCard, BentoGrid };

And this is my cards:
import { BellIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";

import { BentoCard, BentoGrid } from "@/components/magicui/bento-grid";

const features = [
  {
    id: "introduction",
    title: "INTRODUCTION",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-1 row-end-2 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-4 md:row-start-1 md:row-end-2 lg:row-start-1 lg:col-start-1 lg:row-end-2 lg:col-end-4",
  },
  {
    id: "profile-picture",
    title: "PROFILE PICTURE",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-2 row-end-6 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-4 md:row-start-2 md:row-end-5 lg:row-start-2 lg:col-start-1 lg:row-end-5 lg:col-end-4",
  },
  {
    id: "icon-1",
    title: "ICON 1",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-6 row-end-7 md:col-start-4 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-1 md:row-end-2 lg:row-start-1 lg:col-start-4 lg:row-end-2 lg:col-end-5",
  },
  {
    id: "icon-2",
    title: "ICON 2",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-2 col-end-3 row-start-6 row-end-7 md:col-start-4 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-2 md:row-end-3 lg:row-start-2 lg:col-start-4 lg:row-end-3 lg:col-end-5",
  },
  {
    id: "icon-3",
    title: "ICON 3",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-7 row-end-8 md:col-start-4 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-3 md:row-end-4 lg:row-start-3 lg:col-start-4 lg:row-end-4 lg:col-end-5",
  },
  {
    id: "icon-4",
    title: "ICON 4",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-2 col-end-3 row-start-7 row-end-8 md:col-start-4 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-4 md:row-end-5 lg:row-start-4 lg:col-start-4 lg:row-end-4 lg:col-end-5",
  },
  {
    id: "time-zone",
    title: "TIME_ZONE",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-8 row-end-9 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-5 md:row-end-6 lg:row-start-5 lg:col-start-1 lg:row-end-6 lg:col-end-5",
  },
  {
    id: "about-me",
    title: "ABOUT ME",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-9 row-end-11 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-6 md:row-end-8 lg:row-start-1 lg:col-start-5 lg:row-end-3 lg:col-end-9",
  },
  {
    id: "tech-stack",
    title: "TECH STACK",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-11 row-end-13 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-8 md:row-end-10 lg:row-start-1 lg:col-start-9 lg:row-end-3 lg:col-end-13",
  },
  {
    id: "projects",
    title: "PROJECTS",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-13 row-end-16 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-10 md:row-end-13 lg:row-start-3 lg:col-start-5 lg:row-end-6 lg:col-end-13",
  },
  {
    id: "appareance",
    title: "APPAREANCE",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-16 row-end-17 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-13 md:row-end-14 lg:row-start-6 lg:col-start-1 lg:row-end-7 lg:col-end-4",
  },
  {
    id: "about-now",
    title: "ABOUT-NOW",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-17 row-end-18 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-14 md:row-end-15 lg:row-start-6 lg:col-start-4 lg:row-end-7 lg:col-end-7",
  },
  {
    id: "signature",
    title: "SIGNATURE",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-18 row-end-19 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-15 md:row-end-16 lg:row-start-6 lg:col-start-7 lg:row-end-7 lg:col-end-10",
  },
  {
    id: "footer",
    title: "FOOTER",
    Icon: BellIcon,
    description: "",
    href: "",
    cta: "",
    background: "",
    className:
      "col-start-1 col-end-3 row-start-19 row-end-20 md:col-start-1 md:col-end-5 md:row-start-17 md:row-end-18 lg:row-start-6 lg:col-start-10 lg:row-end-7 lg:col-end-13",
  },
];

export async function BentoDemo() {
  return (
    <div className="lg:h-screen lg:flex lg:items-center lg:justify-center lg:p-12">
    <BentoGrid className="">
      {features.map((feature) => (
        <BentoCard key={feature.id} {...feature} />
      ))}
    </BentoGrid>
  </div>
  );
}

I've tried messing around with the aspect ratio and everything but it didn't seem to work at all. The lines there appears to be stretched in any case.
